# Delete Firefox JavaScript console history?

Tags: javascript, security, privacy, firefox

How do I the clear the command history of Firefox's JavaScript console? Clearing all history, cookies, cache, etc., doesn't clear the JavaScript console history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter this in the console:

> `clearHistory()`
>
> *New in Firefox 39.* Just like a normal command line, the console command line [remembers the commands you've typed](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/the_command_line_interpreter/index.html#command-line-interpreter-execution-history). Use this function to clear the console's command history.